# post photos to user wall via graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a ajax call that returns a filename(an image). The file is then posted in the user's wall who was logged in.

```
function grabscreen(){
    $("#load-image").css("display","block");        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/grabscreen.php",
        data:{'found':toSend},
        success: function (result) {
            alert("ajaxreturn"+result);
            var imgUrl = 'http://192.168.100.1/public/FACEBOOKALL/images/'+result;
            FB.api('/me/photos','post',{
                message     : 'This is the message',
                link        : 'http://192.168.100.1/public/FACEBOOKALL/',
                name        : 'Test App',
                url     : imgUrl,
                description : 'Tryin to post images on wall'
            },function(response){

                if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert("some error");
                    grabscreen();

                } else {
                    $("#load-image").css("display","none");
            }
            }
            );
        }
    });

}
```

The problem is that I'm always getting an error(via popup "some error") after getting the filename as popup alert indicating the filename is returned successfully but FB.api is throwing some error.

However,if I give `FB.api('/me/feed',..` instead of `FB.api('/me/photos',..` But that is not the desired goal. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of alert your own rather meaningless error message, look at what `response` actually contains (f.e. by logging it to your browser’s console).

Comment: did that.. the output in console was [object Object]

Comment: Well then _click_ on that to see what it contains.

Comment: i used console.log(response)...and it gave [object Object] in console.. but not clickable.

Comment: Then you are using a browser that no good for development … try Chrome’s developer tools, or Firebug.

Comment: The IP address you are using in your image URL is a local one – if you want Facebook to read the image data from an URL, than it has to be a publicly available one.